# Cell formula to check if Column X completely contains Column A?

Tags: excel, contains

I'm looking for a way to set a cell to "1" if column X completely contains column A (ie. every cell in column A can be found in column X), otherwise set the cell to 0.

Here is an example of what I mean:
http://screencast.com/t/uaQWsRekpsvO

My goal is the array on the right that shows for all of X Y and Z whether each one fully contains A B or C. I just made that array manually to illustrate my problem, how can I use a formula to generate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in J2 and copy/drag over and down:

```
=1*(SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),INDEX($E:$G,0,ROW(1:1)),0))))=COUNT(A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: If column **A** contains an empty cell, must column **Z** also contain an empty cell ??

Comment: This assumes no empty cells in Columns A:C data.  I can play a little to see if I can make it work.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent fixed it to not care if there are blanks in the datasets.  See edit.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I tried to make it as robust as possible.  I did not consider that there may be blanks in the middle of the data in A:C.  Thanks for making me see the error of my assumption.